# Is a 3 hours layover in Beijing (PEK) enough?

Tags: air-travel, china, layovers, pek, air-china

I have read some crazy horror stories about PEK airport, so I'm a bit worried right now :(

Schedule is Milan (MXP) - Beijing (PEK) - Tokyo (HND), then the other way around.
Will leave on August 1st.

Do you think 3 hours layover in PEK is enough? (Both legs on the same ticket and both AirChina)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems mostly safe. Usually 3 hours are enough. Some months ago we had a problem with Pakistan, so most airlines should not flight over it. OTOH I assume the plane will flight mush more north.

In any case, from [FlightRadar24 flight CA950](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ca950), it is often on time. Few times just less then 1 hour delay (and twice with 1h30 delay). So it should be feasible.

But travel is about unforeseen circumstances, so try to think a plan B (do they have later flight to Japan? Prepare the alternative: it is simple to discuss, if you have already some ideas). Get on your cabin luggage also stuff for one extra night (and day).

Comment: I like so much negative votes without any hits to me on what to improve.

Comment: Thanks! Thanks for sharing the website as well ^^